# Possible Async Issue - createEffect updates slice before it completes async http operation

Tags: angular, ngrx

I encounter strange behaviour.

Produce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nk45eb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Fdeployment.effects.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Fdeployment.slice.ts

Issue:
When calling action creator which calls effect, to get data from http, it return first response to action creator, updates the slice (with undefined), and then http is resolved and returned data. (we need to await http before continue and get data)

I have tried few different approaches:

```
getPipelineLogs$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(DeploymentActions.getPipelineLogs),
  switchMap((currentValue) => {
    return this.http.get<any>(
      `${this.apiBase}/pipelines/${currentValue.pipelineId}/logs`,
      this.bufferHttpOptions
    )
  }),
  map((result) => {
    return DeploymentActions.setPipelineLogs({ name: result.logName, data: result.logData });
  }),
  catchError((e) => of(DeploymentActions.error(e)))
)
);
```

I have tried also to add .pipe() on the request itself:

```
getPipelineLogs$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(DeploymentActions.getPipelineLogs),
  switchMap((currentValue) => {
    return this.http.get<any>(
      `${this.apiBase}/pipelines/${currentValue.pipelineId}/logs`,
      this.bufferHttpOptions
    )
      .pipe(
        map((result) => {
          return DeploymentActions.setPipelineLogs({ name: result.logName, data: result.logData });
        }),
        catchError((e) => of(DeploymentActions.error(e)))
      )
  })
)
);
```

but it aways first return response to action creator(updating slice with undefined) and then go back and resolve the http.get.

I also tried to change switchMap to exhaustMap, and different operator in the equation, but didn't make it work to await http and then continue with next operator.

Can you help on this, thanks so much!

Please provide a link to a minimal reproduction of the bug
No response

Please provide the exception or error you saw
No errors. Http request must be done in order to proceed.
Please provide the environment you discovered this bug in (run ng version)

- Angular CLI: 14.2.2
- Node: v18.4.0
- yarn: 1.22.19

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say with just this code and no reproduction.
My guess would be `this.bufferHttpOptions` and that you're streaming the http response. Resulting that the first time is undefined, and the second time that the http call is completed and returned a response.

UPDATE: @Tsvetelin this is the desired behavior.
Effects are asynchronous, and you can select to the store state to retrieve the updates (reactive programming).
For example, add a log statement in the select subscription and you'll see that the data gets updated.

Comment: this.bufferHttpOptions is just setting up headers:

 bufferHttpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ contentType: 'application/zip' }),
  };
, will try to make a reproduction and paste it here

Comment: Hello Tim, here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nk45eb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Fdeployment.effects.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Fdeployment.slice.ts

Comment: Owh.. I was looking at wrong direction. Indeed this is normal behaviour and I was able to just follow SAGA pattern how to update the store and how to execute Effect and Effect to execute another actions etc...

Answer (score 0):

Following pattern of how to update store and how to trigger effects:
[image]